# How can multiple values in TextBox be saved as multiple rows in a table?

Tags: asp.net

User should be allowed to add multiple values in TextBox ( for example 3 Names ). When Enter button is clicked, the 3 names should be saved in 3 rows (as 3 entries ) of a table.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,
Vanu

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what your separator will be, e.g., a line feed or a blank space. Then you can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to create a string array of your elements. Then, loop through the array and do an `INSERT` for each.

Comment: Thank You very much for the quick response. Let me try and will respond back